# En conversation, une utilisation particulière de « comprendre »

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

En anglais, j'utilise très souvent le phrase « I understand that ... » pour vouloir dire que j'ai entendu dire quelque chose mais c'est peut-être faux, le laissant ouvert à correction.

A-t-il le même sens en français ? Sinon, y a-t-il un autre mot pour ça?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't use the literal translation; the ways to render "understand" are several, and you can make use of the literal translation of "understand" *if is somewhat modified*; here below are a few means of doing that.

*Specifically your translation*

- **D'après ce que je comprends** … (*when the context implies that hearsay is the origin; however, after a somewhat unclear explanation someone has just given you, it's perfectly correct to use this expression so as to tell them that you think you understood their meaning.*)
  ex. D'après ce je comprends vous ne viendrez plus travailler le samedi, est-ce correct ?
- **Si je comprends bien**, … (*same remark as above*)
- On m'a **laissé entendre** que …
- **D'après ce que j'ai entendu dire** …
- Je **crois savoir d'après ce que [disent les gens/ dit untel]** que

*It is not explicit anymore that what you know is due to the fact that people are talking about it; it might be the product of your thinking as well.*

- Je **crois comprendre** qu'il y a un autre moyen de faire cela ; c'est vrai ?
- Il **semblerait (être le cas)** (d'après ce que je comprends)  que …
- **Si je comprends bien**, il y a  autre moyen de faire cela.
- Je **crois savoir** que …